# Can not install Samba?

Tags: samba

I have tried installing Samba using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs,
sudo apt-get install samba, 
sudo apt-get install samba4,
sudo apt-get install samba smbclient,
```

But it will not install?

It tells me that is missing, obsolete or only available from another source?

Please take it easy one me as i am a first time user. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want to install Samba to access a samba share (e.g., Windows) or provide a server (i.e., allow others access your stuff using SMB)?

Comment: I was hoping to use it as a file server for 3-5 other Windows 7 based PC's. I have 4 1TB disks already full and another 2 2TB disks empty. I slapped the hardware together out of a VIA Epia M10000N and 1GB of RAM. I'm not sure it is going to be enough but i'd like to try before spending money on new hardware.

Comment: The hardware is fine for a server I use a celeron 1.1 ghz with 512mb of ram works fine. Can you add the error message to your question it will help a lot and also which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Probably you don't have all the required repositories activated. I prefer to manage repositories using the Software Center or Synaptic, so if you only have a command line you'll have to look for the commands to view/modify the repository list youtrself.

Comment: Looks like i got it to work using the GUI instead. All up to date now as far as i can tell. Using 11.10 at the moment. It's painfully slow compared to my i7 rig but that is no fault of Ubuntu's. I'll report back if i'm wrong :) Thanks guys.

Comment: Please post the output of the command:
`cat /etc/lsb-release`